# Detect input form element changes performed by other JS/JQuery methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to detect non-user changes in a JQuery form input called `eur_date`. That changes are performed by a JS script from a bootstrap datepicker script.

I've tried with the following snippets but it doesn't work when I select the date:

```
$(document).on('change', '#eur_date', function(){
    alert('element changed');
});
```

```
$('#eur_date').on('change', function(){
    alert('element changed');
});
```

The debugger don't show errors and the code doesn't run how I've expected.

How could I detect the changes in `eur_date` element when it isn't modified by the user?

Comment: What kind of 'changes' happen to the `#eur_date` field? Are we talking about the `value` of the field, or another property, or the HTML itself?

Comment: The change consists in `#eur_date` value modification performed by bootstrap datepicker.

Comment: In which case you need to use the `changeDate` event. See the documentation: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html